# Groupby & Sum from occurance of a particular value till the occurance of another particular value or the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe as below.
I want to `groupby` 'user' & 'eve' and `sum` 'Ses' till 100/200 & from 100 to 200.
Also, return the value of column 'Name' where 100/200 occurs.

If after an hundred, there is no 100 or 200 (like last row in group a & 123 or a & 456), ignore it.

```
User    eve Ses ID  Name
a   123 1   10  a
a   123 2   11  a
a   123 3   12  a
a   123 4   13  a
a   123 3   100 xyz
a   123 6   10  a
a   456 1   11  a
a   456 2   12  a
a   456 3   13  a
a   456 4   40  a
a   456 1   100 mno
a   456 14  10  a
a   456 7   20  a
a   456 8   30  a
a   456 12  200 pqr
a   456 10  10  a
b   123 1   20  a
b   123 2   30  a
b   123 3   40  a
b   123 4   50  a
b   123 1   70  a
b   123 6   100 abc
b   888 1   20  a
b   888 1   200 jkl
b   888 3   10  a
b   888 4   20  a
b   888 5   30  a
b   888 1   100 rrr
b   888 7   50  a
b   888 8   70  a
```

The expected output for the above input df is a df below.

```
User    eve Ses Name
a   123 13  xyz
a   456 11  mno
a   456 41  pqr
b   123 17  abc
b   888 2   jkl
b   888 13  rrr
```

Comment: Someone down-voted this question. Can that person explain why? It will help me improve.

Comment: I didn't downvote but what did you try?

Comment: I don't know where to start. I tried `df.groupby(['User','eve'],sort=False).apply(lambda x: x[x['ID'].isin([100,200]),'ses'].sum())` but i get an error(this will not get the answer i want but it is a start none the less).

Comment: If i do `df.index[(df['ID']==100) | (df['ID']==200)]` i get the index of where 100 & 200 is present, can anyone guide who i can use this to get the output i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my approach:

```
# valid IDs
df['valids'] = df['ID'].isin([100,200])

# mask the trailing non-hundred ids
heads = (df['ID'].where(df['valids'])
             .groupby([df['User'],df['eve']])
             .bfill().notnull()
        )
df = df[heads]

# groupby and output:
(df.groupby(['User','eve', df['valids'].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()],
           as_index=False)
   .agg({'Ses':'sum', 'Name':'last'})
)
```

Output:

```
  User  eve  Ses Name
0    a  123   13  xyz
1    a  456   11  mno
2    a  456   41  pqr
3    b  123   17  abc
4    b  888    2  jkl
5    b  888   13  rrr
```

Comment: Thank you. This works :-). Is this fast as well? In my actual dataframe, there are about 10Million rows. Thanks.

Comment: Depend on your data. Usually `groupby` on several columns would not be so fast. But This is the most optimized I can think of.

Comment: Quang , can you explain how the bfill works to find the and # mask the trailing non-hundred ids. It would help me, i am was stuck on that part.

Comment: @oppressionslayer basically, `where` mask all the non-hundred as `nan`. Then `bfill()` fills all the previous `nan` with the hundred id after them, except for the trailing `nan`.

Comment: Yes, that helps, the  documentation is light (non-existent ) on bfill, so it definitely helps me understand how you accomplished it.

Comment: ok, i see from list(df['ID'].where(df['valids']).groupby([df['User'],df['eve']])) how bfill works. Thanks Quang, this will help. Pandas should update their documenation on it, it's quite useful